# Find all tables associated with a view

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I need to find all tables that are used in some of my views.  These views may contain other views and so I would need those tables returned and so on.  My `V` are the view names and `T` are the names of the tables.

```
Views | Tables
 V1   |   T1
 V2   |   T2
 V3   |   T3
      |   T4
      |   T5
```

Now lets say my views contain the following references:

```
View | References
 V1  |   T1, T2
 V2  |   V1, T5
 V3  |   V1, V2, T3
```

So given `V1` I need the names of `T1` and `T2` returned.

Given `V2` I need `T1`, `T2` and `T5`.

Given `V3` I need `T1`, `T2`, `T3` and `T5`

Comment: I hope you're after this so you can start unraveling it. "Death by 1,000 views."

Comment: Doing some Business Intelligence stuff and some people are asking for this information, I'm afraid.  =P

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sys.dm_sql_referenced_entities` to select the tables and views that an object is dependent on. See the [Books Online article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677185%28v=sql.100%29.aspx).

This cte will recursively select tables from views that appear in the results of sys.dm_sql_referenced_entities. It should work for you. See the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0cc9e/1)

```
DECLARE @viewName sysname = 'dbo.V3'
;WITH cteViews AS(
    SELECT 
         re.referenced_id
        ,o.type_desc    
        ,SCHEMA_NAME(o.schema_id) AS [schema]
        ,o.name
    FROM sys.dm_sql_referenced_entities (@viewName, 'OBJECT') re
    JOIN sys.objects o ON re.referenced_id = o.object_id 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
         viewTables.referenced_id
        ,viewTables.type_desc
        ,viewTables.[schema]
        ,viewTables.name
    FROM cteViews cte
    OUTER APPLY(
        SELECT
             re.referenced_id
            ,o.type_desc    
            ,SCHEMA_NAME(o.schema_id) AS [schema]
            ,o.name
        FROM sys.dm_sql_referenced_entities (cte.[schema] + '.' + cte.name, 'OBJECT') re
        JOIN sys.objects o ON re.referenced_id = o.object_id 
        WHERE o.type_desc = 'USER_TABLE'
    ) AS viewTables
    WHERE cte.type_desc = 'VIEW'    
)
SELECT 
    [schema]
    ,name
FROM cteViews
WHERE type_desc <> 'VIEW'
ORDER BY name
```

There is also a feature available in SSMS that will allow you to view an object's dependencies. Right click the view in object explorer then select "View Dependencies". Then select the radio button "Objects on which 'view name' depends".

Comment: Yes but if a view is dependent on other views, will this give me the tables in the dependent views as well?  If a view is dependent on 5 other views, I don't want those returned, I want the tables those other views reference.

Comment: I updated my answer to include a recursive CTE that should help you.

Comment: I ran this against my schema.  I have a view that depends on 22 tables and 1 additional view.  Your query returns 6 rows.  Any ideas?